# Steer VS2013 Excel automation into either Excel 2010 or 2013 when both are installed

Tags: c#, excel, automation, add-in

While using Visual Studio 2013/C# to create Excel automation ... I have both Office 2010 and Office 2013 on my machine. How do I create an add-in that will install into Excel 2010 or on another case install into 2013, my choice. Will creating a new 2010 or 2013 add-in project do the trick or do I have to configure something to steer it to one or the other? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an add-in per version of Office you wish to target. i.e. one for 2010; another for 2013 and so forth. The Office types used in each add-in are locked to that version of office.  COM and Automation does allow you to create objects from *version-independent PROG IDs* but that's another story.

However if done right, you could abstract out some of your core code to be shared across Office installations.